# vuejs integration with firebase gives "createUser is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I am new in the Vue.js and I'm trying to integrate the Firebase with the Vue.js app in this app I'm having two fields and i want to store them into the database of the Firebase but it gives me the error:-

```
<template>
 <div class="container">
  <div class= "row">
   <div class= "col-xs-12 co-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h1>Http</h1>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Username</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="username">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Mail</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="email">
     </div>
     <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
 import firebase from 'firebase'

 var config = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAQoOXm69M5WKRjRL_ee4wkh4Bbp7mSF3E",
  authDomain: "vuejs-http-11c9f.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://vuejs-http-11c9f.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "vuejs-http-11c9f",
  storageBucket: "vuejs-http-11c9f.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "messenger_id"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

export default {
data() {
return{
    username:'',
    email:''
  };

methods:{

 submit(){
  firebase.createUser(this.username, this.email)
   .then((result) => {
     console.log(result);
   }).catch((err) => {
     console.log(err)
   });
 }
}
}
```

The error I'm facing on the click of the submit button is

> Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_firebase___default.a.createUser is not a function

How I will I solve this error?

Comment: `createUser` is admin sdk function, check docs of managing users on client side properly https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

Comment: @MaxSinev see my full code and tell me where the error is

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `createUser` method you are trying to call. Where did you find that code? To learn how to create an email+password user in Firebase, have a look at this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#create_a_password_based_account

Comment: You say "I'm having two fields and i want to store them into the database". Do you just want to store the username and email fields or do you want to create a new user account?

Answer (score 1):

I think that on your submit method, you are missing the `.auth()`. Your submit method should look something like this:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.username, this.email)
 .then((result) => {
   console.log(result);
 }).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err)
});
```

}

Check: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth

Comment: Will this data I will entered is stored in the database? @jamieRios

Comment: Yes, if the request is successful, you will see it from the authentication section on the Firebase console. But unless you do it explicitly, it will not be saved on Firestore nor Realtime Database.